# how to remove first menu from ag-grid column menu

Tags: ag-grid

Is there an option to remove first menu from ag-grid column menu?
I mean the menu with 'pinSubMenu', 'valueAggSubMenu', 'autoSizeThis', etc.

I want to open the context menu and to see first the filter menu and second the columns visibility menu.

I tried to do this, but it still opens empty menu and I need to navigate to my filter menu:

```
function getMainMenuItems(params) {
    var countryMenuItems = [];
    var itemsToExclude = [
        'separator', 'pinSubMenu', 'valueAggSubMenu', 'autoSizeThis', 'autoSizeAll', 'rowGroup', 'rowUnGroup',
        'resetColumns', 'expandAll', 'contractAll','toolPanel'
    ];
    params.defaultItems.forEach(function(item) {
        if (itemsToExclude.indexOf(item) < 0) {
            countryMenuItems.push(item);
        }
    });
    return countryMenuItems;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should be able to accomplish what you want to do within the gridOptions:

```
gridOptions = {
    ...
    suppressMenuMainPanel: true,
    ...
}
```

You can also suppress any of the panels of the column menu:

```
gridOptions = {
    ...
    suppressMenuMainPanel: true,
    suppressMenuColumnPanel: true,
    suppressMenuFilterPanel: true,
    ...
}
```

This is supposing that you are using the Enterprise version, which I assumed you were based on your usage of the `getMainMenuItems` function

Comment: is that to be put in column defs. by putting to col defs - not working, filter params - not working.

Comment: @VISHALDAGA No... it is to be put under your gridOptions... as it shows in the answer

Comment: This answer is meanwhile deprecated - as of now you have to define the menu in every column-definition: `menuTabs:['generalMenuTab','gibberishMenuTab']` (see the docs here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=suppressMenuColumnPanel&gsc.sort=)

Comment: How do you remove that menu entirely?

Comment: @DominicTobias Setting [`suppressMenu: true`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `menuTabs` in the `colDef` object:

```
{
    headerName: "ID",
    field: "id",
    menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab','generalMenuTab','columnsMenuTab']
}
```

See more details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu).